# How to make a Try match in Scala that handles nulls?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Im tying to make a cache client and when I get the object I have one of three scenarios, either a) I get the object, b) I get null or c) the cache throws out a error. To handle these Im trying to do something like this where in a hit I return something, but on both a miss and a error I return None, but run different functions.

```
Try { cache.get(key) } match {
      case Success(cacheValue) => {
        onHit()
        Some(cacheValue)
      }
      case Success(null) => {
        onMiss()
        None
      }
      case Failure(e) => {
        onError(e)
        None
      }
    }
```

But when I try to run it I get this error

```
[scalac-2.12]  found   : Null(null)
[scalac-2.12]  required: Nothing
[scalac-2.12]       case Success(null) => {
```

And I don't know what it means or how to fix it. Im not super familiar with scala but I thought that having a Success(null) should work? Any help or advise is appreciated.

Comment: The best is to wrap the value in an **Option**.

Comment: As asked in earlier comments, please add the definition of `cache`, and its `get` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In scala `null` is an object of type `Null`, unless another type specified. E.g. in declaration `val a = null` inferred type of `a` is `Null`, so you need to specify type more precisely. So, in your case compiler complains that `Null` does not match with `V` type from `cache.get` or `Nothing` - because this type inherits all types in the Scala system.

In your case, you can proceed with some like this (code snippet changed to make it work and compile):

```
import scala.util._

//Cache method example
def cacheGet(key: String): String = null

val result = Try(cacheGet("key")) match {
  case Success(cacheValue) if cacheValue != null => {
    println("Value is not null")
    Some(cacheValue)
  }
  case Success(_) => {
    println("Value is null")
    None
  }
  case Failure(e) => {
    println("Failure: $e")
    None
  }
}

println(result)
```

Which will printout:

```
Value is null
None
```

Working Scatie example: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/7GSaMGIcTte9MwwDr361Dw

Comment: Add of course adding in a if check with the success! Thanks!